# C++ istream conditional direct initialization w/ ternary operator

Tags: c++11, g++, ifstream, ternary-operator

Given this issue-exemplifing minimal code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using std::ifstream;
using std::string;

string TEST_PATH;
string TRAIN_PATH;

enum DataContext
{
    TRAINING, TESTING
};

void StreamData(DataContext context)
{
    ifstream dataFile = (context == TRAINING) ? ifstream(TRAIN_PATH) : ifstream(TEST_PATH);

    dataFile.close();
}

void StreamData2(DataContext context)
{
    ifstream datafile;
    datafile.open((context == TRAINING) ? TRAIN_PATH: TEST_PATH);

    datafile.close();
}


int main()
{
    StreamData(TRAINING);
    StreamData2(TRAINING);

    return 0;
}
```

I am implementing an AI Iterative Dichotomizer, but that isn't relevant to this issue. What is relevant are two external testfiles, one with training data and one with testing data. Certain control flow is governed by what type of data is being dealt with at the time, a simple enum is used to simplify such association.

StreamData aims to conditionally direct initialize an ifstream based on a check of the current context. It does so with the ternary operator. In Visual Studio(which means nothing), but also in cygwin g++ v5.1.0, the use of the StreamData function as written compiles successfully, and executes per my expectations.(in my real program, something is actually returned). However, in Debian, g++ v4.9.2, the use of that function produces an essay of compiler-ese. I won't copy the whole output, unless it becomes necessary, but the highlights include a warning that g++ is deleting the **default** ifstream constuctor because it would be ill-formed. Then a forceful criticism of attempting to call a deleted function.

"g++ -o TT -std=c++11 ./ThisCode.cpp" is the g++ command executed in both environments.

StreamData2 is a natural alternative to StreamData, and it compiles fine everywhere.

My problem is solved with StreamData2. I'm left with a question. Is StreamData valid C++11/use of the ternary operator? Is compilation failure with the lesser revision of g++ a bug/mal-implementation?

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: The code looks OK to me. `dataFile` in `StreamData` is actually initialized with a move constructor, moving from a temporary that the ternary operator produces. g++ v4.9.2 , or the standard library that ships with it, must be non-conforming (aka buggy) in some way.